# how to resolve errors when inserting data into mysql using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to enter data into mysql using node.js but it is giving me an error when Iam typing data as : "icecream's" or "balloon/mycolors" etc. When Iam using the symbols such as / or ' or " or \ Iam getting an error. So please tell me how could this type of data can be entered.

If I have entered data as icecream's I must see that the data is entered into mysql as icecream's
If I have entered data as balloon/ I must see that data is entered into mysql as balloon/

I have entered the code as follows:

```
conn.query(`insert into questions (question,username,title,qdate) values ('${req.body.body}','${req.session.uname}','${req.body.title}',now())`,function(err,result){
    if(err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: _What_ error and _how_ are you trying to insert your data ? I guess you have to escape special char, depending on your query, or use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the npm package [sql-escape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-escape). By doing so, ensure your data is of type string and instead of using the string itself, use `escape(<string>)` instead.